# I want to get last modified date in php (stat failed)

Tags: php, filemtime

what's wrong with my code? this code displays a warning like

> Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for..

and shows the wrong date as a modified date.

```
$i = 0;
  while ($i < count($files)) {
      $current_file = $files[$i];
      echo "Modified:".date("F d YH:i:s.",filemtime($current_file)); 
      $i++;
  }
```

I tried many times by searching google. but not fixed yet.

Comment: Check File path, Print file path and Check It is proper or not, This kind of things happen If file not exist or not found

Comment: I checked by printing file name and file type. that's worked. But for filemtime not works

Comment: The data may be cached - check - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: what's your server specs?

Comment: It could happen if the real path of the file is not recognized by filemtime(), 
you can the following question -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386082/filemtime-warning-stat-failed-for

Comment: How do you print the file type? please add to the question.